# How to increase amplitude of "wavyness" of photon propagator (tikz-feynman)

Tags: tikz-feynman

I am trying to draw a Feynman diagram with a couple of manually placed vertices. Unfortunately the photon and gluon propagators end up being so narrow that they can barely be seen (if it is curly or wavy). I tried to scale the figure and the coordinates, but it did not help. How can I make the line decorations more visible? (Not thicker but rather just scaled up.)

Note: As you see I also have a straight line running down the middle of the red parts. I would like to keep this as it is.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}


\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=2, every node/.style={scale=1.5}]
      \begin{feynman}
      
      \def\xscale{1.0cm}
      \def\yscale{1.0cm}
    
        \vertex [particle] (i1) at (-1*\xscale,1*\yscale) {$p$};
        \vertex [particle](i2) at (-1*\xscale,-1*\yscale) {$p$};
        \vertex [blob, scale=0.7, pattern=north east lines, pattern color=blue] (pp) at (0*\xscale,0*\yscale) {};
        \vertex [dot, scale=1.2] (vg1) at (1*\xscale,1*\yscale) {};
        \vertex [dot, scale=1.2] (vg2) at (1*\xscale,-1*\yscale) {};
        \vertex [particle] (vq1) at (1.5*\xscale,1.75*\yscale) {$q$};
        \vertex [particle] (vq2) at (1.7*\xscale,1.25*\yscale) {$q$};
        \vertex [particle] (vq3) at (1.5*\xscale,-1.75*\yscale) {$q$};
        \vertex [particle] (vq4) at (1.7*\xscale,-1.25*\yscale) {$q$};
        \vertex [vertex] (vc1) at (2.5*\xscale, 1.0*\yscale) {};
        \vertex [vertex] (vc2) at (2.5*\xscale,-1.0*\yscale) {};
        
    
        \diagram* {
          (i1) -- [double, very thick] (pp),
          (i2) -- [double, very thick] (pp),
          (pp) -- [plain, gluon, red] (vg1),
          (pp) -- [plain, gluon, red ] (vg2),
          (vg1) -- (vq1),
          (vg1) -- (vq2),
          (vg1) -- [plain, boson, red] (vc1),
          (vg2) -- (vq3),
          (vg2) -- (vq4),
          (vg2) -- [plain, boson, red] (vc2),
        };
      \end{feynman}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome in this community. Can, please, you add a full compilable code?

Comment: Thank you @Sebastiano. I updated the example now it compiles nicely.

Comment: I had upvoted before :-)...thank you very much for your cooperation.